# enable both password and public key authentication with OpenSSH in RHEL 5

Tags: ssh, rhel5

I have found solution for RHEL 6 and that was working but when i tried the same for RHEL 5, i got below error:

> Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 122: Bad configuration
>   option: AuthenticationMethods /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad
>   configuration options

Answer (score 0):

This feature was not introduced until openSSH 6.2 which is not available for RHEL 5 as it ships with openSSH 4.3.

As per: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.2

```
 sshd(8): Added support for multiple required authentication in SSH
   protocol 2 via an AuthenticationMethods option. This option lists
   one or more comma-separated lists of authentication method names.
   Successful completion of all the methods in any list is required for
   authentication to complete. This allows, for example, requiring a
   user having to authenticate via public key or GSSAPI before they
   are offered password authentication.
```

Previously this had to be done using various patches and there was a way to do this using a rather hacky forcecommand way but that broke SFTP and is generally a very bad idea.

If I were you, I'd simply use PKI authentication on the older server for security reasons alone.